# Random crash (sigabrt) when running C-linked Android app on Chromebooks

Tags: android, java-native-interface, sigabrt, chromebook

I'm running my app that contains C code built in with JNI on Chromebooks. After some time using the app (5-20 mins) and not when any specific action is taking place the app crashes. This crash does not occur when running the same app on a phone or tablet.

I was able to get the tombstone file off and extract the stacktrace. I would normally expect to see a call to a function in my program somewhere in the trace, but there is none here. Thus, I have no idea where to begin debugging this. The only think I see of interest is the calls to libsupportjni.so which leads me to believe that there is some issue in the C code, or perhaps there is something special about the JNI implementation on Chromebooks that isn't present on phones/tablets? Any ideas? Stacktrace follows:

```
2019-01-10 14:01:48.022 1879-1965/  A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1965 (Studio:Agent)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/cyan/cyan_cheets:7.1.1/R71-11151.59.0/5167872:user/release-keys'
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG: pid: 1879, tid: 1965, name: Studio:Agent  >>> appname.redacted <<<
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00000757  ecx 000007ad  edx 00000006
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     esi e6730978  edi e6730920
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b
2019-01-10 14:01:48.105 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     eip ed060a40  ebp e6730778  esp e673071c  flags 00000296
2019-01-10 14:01:48.115 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000a40  [vdso:ed060000] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0008aafc  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+28)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00086355  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+85)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00036d3a  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+42)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0002e246  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+86)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 001d8664  /data/app/appname.redacted-2/lib/x86/libsupportjni.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+468)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 001a9078  /data/app/appname.redacted-2/lib/x86/libsupportjni.so (_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+24)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 001a910f  /data/app/appname.redacted-2/lib/x86/libsupportjni.so (_ZSt9terminatev+31)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 001d5a09  /data/app/appname.redacted-2/lib/x86/libsupportjni.so
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00085ab2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0002f73e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
2019-01-10 14:01:48.116 3155-3155/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0002d3f6  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
2019-01-10 14:01:49.181 53-3156/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity appname.redacted/.Activity
```

Comment: Does this happen when you install the prebuilt APK (e.g. via Google Play), or only when you run the app via Android Studio? In the latter case, try disabling the profiling feature in Android Studio.

Comment: @Michael Happens in both situations, with the production app installed from an APK and the debug version run via Android Studio.